# What is the first day of the 2011 Star Wars advent calendar supposed to be?

Tags: star-wars, advent-calendar

I opened the Star Wars Advent Calendar 2011 early and I don't get what the set on the first day is. I'm not much of a Star Wars fan I guess. I can't identify it as any particular ship and my only guess is it's a part of a bigger set for later.

And the worst part is I can't find it on the box anywhere. Lego is usually really good with the imagery and usually exaggerates the final product (by making it look bigger or whatever) but it seems only a fraction of the 25 mini models are shown on the box.

Has anyone else opened it up?

Comment: Hey! It's not even December, yet! I'll bet you're one of those naugty people who eat all the chocolates early, too! ;-)

Comment: @Kramii I know! I wanted to build something but didn't have a lot of time. Lego should release a set like this for every month!

Comment: I though basic Star Wars knowledge was mandatory in since 1981

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't have it, but BrickLink already has [inventories of all submodels](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=S&catString=390.715.65).

According to them, [day 1](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=7958-2) is a Republic Cruiser. This is a mini version of [7665 — Republic Cruiser](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=7665-1).

They do look quite similar for sets of a such different scale:

[image: 7958-2 — Advent Calendar 2011, Star Wars (Day 1) - Republic Cruiser]
[image: 7665 — Republic Cruiser]

Sadly, Wookiepedia doesn't have a picture of a [republic-class cruiser](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Republic-class_cruiser), but I suppose that's what it is.

Comment: Yes! That's it. And the brinklink link will making identifying the rest way easier. Thanks.

Comment: Technically it's a Consular-Class Cruiser http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Consular-class_space_cruiser I'll get my coat...

Comment: It found ir rather puzzling that LEGO would create a ship for which there's no picture. Nice find.

Answer (score 11):

### Republic Cruiser

[image: http://www.bricklink.com/SL/7958-2.jpg?1]

Is this the one you were looking for? You can see the entire selection of mini-models on [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=7958-1).

Comment: I knew I had to type faster ;-)

Comment: @Joubarc it's not always the fastest that's chosen ;)

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid unless one is seeking enlightenment :-)